# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` bound to an `ObservableCollection<String>` in my ViewModel. This binding works, giving a drop down of the ObservableCollection:

[image]

Here's my Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MembershipsCollection}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Region" Width="SizeToHeader">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style>
                 <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.RegionShortCodeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AccountsViewModel}}}" />
              </Style>
             </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
               <Style>
                  <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.RegionShortCodeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:AccountsView}}}" />
                </Style>
             </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
           </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductCode" Binding="{Binding Path=ProductCode}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>                                                                  
        </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
```

& my ObservableCollection in my ViewModel. This is populated by a method invoked from the constructor:

```
  private ObservableCollection<String> _RegionShortCodeCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<String> RegionShortCodeCollection
    {
        get { return _RegionShortCodeCollection; }
        set
        {
            _RegionShortCodeCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RegionShortCodeCollection");
        }
    }
```

I now want to bind the value of the cell to the actual current value in the Database (The same `ObservableCollection<T>` as PRODUCTCODE in the picture as currently this is obviously blank:

[image]

Is there any way to bind to more than one property with the same column? If not, is there a way around this? Hope it's clear, thanks.

Comment: What is your ItemsSource for the DataGrid? Normally, you'd bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox to the Property of your ItemsSource that holds this value.

Comment: Updated the question Xaml. If I try to bind to the item within the ItemSource Collection I'm getting a 'Additional information: 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction' exception...

Comment: What is this? `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AccountsViewModel}}` And why does the editing style bind to a different AncestorType?

Comment: Also, the DisplayMemberPath binding seems strange to me. You shouldn't need to set this property since you are binding the ItemsSource to a collection of strings....there is no path. And even if you were binding it...it shouldn't be to a collection but rather a string.

Comment: Thanks @LeeO. Xaml has been edited. Still no luck.  'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction' exception when attempting to bind to this collection Item. I can bind to another ObservableCollection<String> no problem...

Comment: Can you add the SelectedItemBinding code you are using and the definition of the property within your MembershipCollection object that it's bound to?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but I don't think you need the Styles for `DataGridComboBoxColumn` -- just use the `ItemsSource` value directly.  As to your question, you should be able to bind the row view-model property to the selected item using `SelectedItemBinding` (or `SelectedValueBinding` if that applies):

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Region" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.RegionShortCodeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:AccountsView}}"
     SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedRegionShortCode,Mode=TwoWay}"
 />
```

Comment: Nothing returned in the UI for this code I'm afraid. I'm essentially trying to view the current value in the cell then click on the drop down to have a list of alternative options, thought this would be easy but as with a lot of WPF/Xaml it becomes extremely verbose very quickly!

Comment: That is because a DataGridColumn is not a part of the visual tree so it can't do the RelativeSource lookup like this. Thus the need for the ElementStyle & EditingElementStyle.